# I am getting import error running brownie python in my erc20 token project

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, brownie, solidity-0.8.x

```
> brownie run scripts/1_deploy_token.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Erc20BrownieProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasLimit 12000000 --mnemonic brownie --port 8545'...
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 53, in run
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 149, in _import_from_path  
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File ".\scripts\1_deploy_token.py", line 1, in <module>
    from brownie import MyToken
ImportError: cannot import name 'MyToken' from 'brownie' (C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\__init__.py)
Terminating local RPC client...
PS E:\ERC20-BROWNIE>
```

Comment: Hi KamalShah! Do you have a link to the repo?

Comment: Please follow the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412439/info-could-not-find-files-for-the-given-patterns-error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem as you.
All I did was change the name of the contract to be the same of that of the solidity file.
In your case I would make sure the solidity filename under the /contracts folder is called MyToken and also the contract initialisation inside Mytoken is called MyToken

```
contract MyToken is ERC20 {

    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("MyToken", "MT") {
```